# random sampling using slice_sample, but with constraints to have equal number of values in some columns

Tags: r

I want to (somewhat)randomly sample 6 rows out of a dataframe, with the caveat that there should be the same number of each cylinder type; so I would want the sample to have two rows with random cars where cyl = 4, two with cyl = 6, and two with cyl = 8. And the only way I can think of doing this would be to subset, sample and rbind the results, like this:

```
data("mtcars")
mt_sample <- rbind(
  (slice_sample((subset(mtcars, cyl == 4)), n=2, replace = FALSE)), 
  (slice_sample((subset(mtcars, cyl == 6)), n=2, replace = FALSE)), 
  (slice_sample((subset(mtcars, cyl == 8)), n=2, replace = FALSE))
)

mt_sample
```

Which feels a bit frankenstein as a solution; is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `subset`ting individually, `sample` and then `rbind`, do a group by operation and `sample`

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(24)
mt_sample2 <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 2, replace = FALSE) %>%
  ungroup
```

-checking with the OP's output

```
all.equal(mt_sample, mt_sample2, check.attributes = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```